# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (15,3) (15,) GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, shapes

I am trying to set the `loss_` function given by the `GradientBoostingClassifier` from `sklearn` but it returns an error which has no sense to me:

Error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-228-587a565619f1> in <module>
      2 for i, pred in enumerate(clf.staged_predict(testX)):
      3     print(testY, pred)
----> 4     test_score[i] = clf.loss_(testY, pred)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_gb_losses.py in __call__(self, y, raw_predictions, sample_weight)
    712 
    713         if sample_weight is None:
--> 714             return np.sum(-1 * (Y * raw_predictions).sum(axis=1) +
    715                           logsumexp(raw_predictions, axis=1))
    716         else:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (15,3) (15,)
```

It is strange because clearly the variables `testY` and `pred`, both have shapes `(15,)`. Could someone explain this to me please?

Code to replicate the error:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

dt = load_iris(as_frame=True)
X, Y = np.array(dt.data), np.array(data.target)

trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=200).fit(trainX, trainY)

test_score = np.empty(len(clf.estimators_))
for i, pred in enumerate(clf.staged_predict(testX)):
    print(testY.shape) # (15,)
    print(pred.shape) # (15,)
    test_score[i] = clf.loss_(testY, pred) # Error here
```

Comment: Might be an actual bug?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the `staged_predict_proba` instead of `staged_predict`.
The loss (and hence the gradients) is calculated with respect to the prediction probability.

This should work for you:

```
for i, pred in enumerate(clf.staged_predict_proba(testX)):
    test_score[i] = clf.loss_(testY, pred)
```